# Problems with 'my'

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I have a program designed to pull lines out of multifasta and run them through THREADER:

```
#¡/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);

my $filename = 'unchar_prot';   #open file
open (my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Error - cannot open file";

my %id2seq = (); #create a hash
my $seq_id = '';
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^>(.+)/) { #Find lines starting in >
        $seq_id = $1;
    } else {
        $id2seq{$seq_id} .= $line; #Store seq and ID on hash
    }
}

open(my $outfile, '>', 'out.txt') or die
close (my $outfile)

while (my ($seq_id, $seq) = each %id2seq) { #Call key and value from hash 
    my ($temp_fh, $prot) = tempfile ("tempXXXX", SUFFIX => '.seq'); #create a temporary file
    print $temp_fh ">$seq_id\n$seq\n"; #print the 2 lines to the temp file 
    my ($out_fh, $out) = tempfile("outXXXX", SUFFIX => '.txt'); # create a temporary outfile 
    system ('nohup threader -p $temp_fh $out_fh cdc6.lst &'); #call threader 
    open($outfile, '>>', 'out.txt');
    print $outfile "$out_fh"; # append the content of the temp out to the main outfile
}
```

When I try to run it I get a lot of issues cropping up with 'my':

> "my" variable $outfile masks earlier declaration in same statement at testfile4.pl line 22.
>
> "my" variable $seq_id masks earlier declaration in same scope at testfile4.pl line 24.
>
> "my" variable $temp_fh masks earlier declaration in same statement at testfile4.pl line 26.
>
> "my" variable $seq_id masks earlier declaration in same statement at testfile4.pl line 26.
>
> "my" variable $seq masks earlier declaration in same statement at testfile4.pl line 26.
>
> syntax error at testfile4.pl line 24, near ") {"
>
> syntax error at testfile4.pl line 31, near "}"
>
> Execution of testfile4.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Does anyone know what's going on here? How can I get it to run?

PS I know there are probably a lot of other issues with how this is written. I'm very much a beginner, I don't need this to be tidy or efficient yet, I just need it to work.

Comment: Carey, just an fyi, and [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36114241/timeline) . We don't ask questions, receive help, then delete the question. That is not how we roll here.

Comment: I realised that the question was kind of stupid

Answer (score 3):

As a hint - any time you get a load of errors like that, it's *usually* because you've missed a semicolon or close bracket.

Like on this line:

```
open(my $outfile, '>', 'out.txt') or die
close (my $outfile)
```

You need a semilcolon there. You also need to not `my` it, because you've already declared `$outfile` as part of the `open` statement.

Of course, it also doesn't make a great deal of sense to be closing it immediately after opening either.

(Also - what's going on with that `!` in the shebang line?)

There's also a few other quite strange things going on here. Like:

```
print $outfile "$out_fh"; # append the content of the temp out to the main outfile
```

I don't think that'll be doing what you want. Because `$out_fh` is a file handle, you'll print "GLOB(0xDEADBEEF)" or similar.

Comment: Thank you, I think I've sorted at least some of the errors now. This is what comes of trying to learn perl on a tight deadline (very messy code)

Comment: @Carey especially when learning or on a tight deadline, it really helps to get one small piece at a time working, using known good input and verifying output

Comment: The best trick is: Turn on strict and warnings. Use `Data::Dumper` to check you're getting what you think you're getting at each point in the program.